# Angularjs Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I copied the angularjs example for unit testing from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing). As its just direct implementation of the example, i am confused with the error thrown.

I work in Linux and using Brackets to as IDE.

Please let know what is the missing element to run the jasmine tests.

**Ouput of Jasmine**

```
PasswordController encountered a declaration exception.       
ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {
  $scope.password = '';
  $scope.grade = function() {
    var size = $scope.password.length;
    if (size > 8) {
      $scope.strength = 'strong';
    } else if (size > 3) {
      $scope.strength = 'medium';
    } else {
      $scope.strength = 'weak';
    }
  };
});
```

**controller-spec.js**

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

**karma-conf.js**

```
 // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
             'app/controllers/*.js',
            'test/controllers/*.js'
    ],
```

**Karma Output**

```
   /var/www/html/angular-jasmine-testing $ kma start karma.conf.js
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 41.0.2272 (Linux)]: Connected on socket vZCR4hAC8uU7LutFNVl3 with id 44440115
Chrome 41.0.2272 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.042 secs / 0.035 secs)
```

[image: Folder structure Image]

Comment: Are you sure you have all those files in your project? Could you post the complete output of karma?

Comment: Karma seems to have run the tests successfully: "Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS". Is it possible that Brackets tries to run the Jasmine specs outside Karma?

Comment: I dont think the issue is with brackets, as i ran a simple javascript test and it got executed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your test working. See the plunkr below:

```
describe("PasswordController", function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $scope = null;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
   $controller('PasswordController', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
  }));

  describe("$scope.grade", function() {
    it("sets the strength to 'strong' if the password length is >8 chars", function() {
      $scope.password = "longerthaneightchars";
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual("strong");
      });
   })

});
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tm9nInc4JS3VlLYSCagc?p=preview)

Comment: I tried your code and it still throws error. But karma is executed. Might be brackets issue as told in comments. I will test with sublime and keep you posted.